# Generate offline OLAP cube programmatically without SSAS

Tags: ssas, olap-cube

I was wondering how can you generate an olap cube programmatically in c# using any relational datasource without using analysis services. A concrete example (something i couldnt find anywhere on the net.)would be appreciated a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can programmatically  create a cube using C# and Analysis Management Objects [AMO](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345091.aspx):

```
        // Create the Adventure Works cube
        Cube cube = db.Cubes.FindByName("Adventure Works");
        if (cube != null)
           cube.Drop();
        db.Cubes.Add("Adventure Works");
```